# C# clearing the thread principal

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you clear the thread principal in c#.

I have a background thread that does a

```
Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

which then copies the resulting Principal back to the main thread

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
```

this works fine.  But, if I log off I want to clear the principal, if I set it to null it does nothing Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null; if I try and set it again via

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
```

I get the error

```
Default principal object cannot be set twice.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to solve this was to create a facade principal and assign that to the thread.  Then behind it you can switch out the current user for a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can reset the principal without shutting down the AppDomain and recreating it.  You only get one shot at calling SetThreadPrincipal.

Assuming that you are using your own custom principal object that you create after ValidateUser; you can probably put a "Logout" method on your principal that resets its internal state to an unauthenticated user.

Comment: That could well be the case.  I have no problem if I call membership.validateuser on the dispatcher thread a few times, it always just writes another principal in.  Maybe I'm trying to update the wrong principal.  Any idea what principal the validateUser updates?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to set the principal for your main thread pass a reference along to background thread and then set the principal using the CurrentPrincipal property.

e.g. mainThead.CurrentPrincipal=Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

When you are finished set it to the original principal